# Getting an error over a right query in SQLITE, why?

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite, debugging

Here's my code:

```
void DatabaseAccess::addPictureToAlbumByName(const std::string& albumName, const Picture& picture)
{
    std::string dbFileName = "GalleryDB.sqlite";
    int doesFileExist = _access(dbFileName.c_str(), 0);
    int res = sqlite3_open(dbFileName.c_str(), &db);

    if (res != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        db = nullptr;
        std::cout << "Failed to open DB" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::string sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO PICTURES (ID,NAME,LOCATION,CREATION_DATE,ALBUM_ID) VALUES (" + std::to_string(picture.getId()) + ",'" + picture.getName() + "','" + picture.getPath() + "','" + picture.getCreationDate() + "',(SELECT ID FROM ALBUMS WHERE NAME = '" + albumName+ "'));";
        std::cout << sqlStatement;
        const char* sqlstate = sqlStatement.c_str();
        char** errMessage = nullptr;
        res = sqlite3_exec(db, sqlstate, nullptr, nullptr, errMessage);
        if (res != SQLITE_OK)
        {

            std::cout << "ERROR: CANNOT INSERT";
        }
    }
}
```

PICTURE and Album are tables in my database:
[image: the tables]

The query is: 
`INSERT INTO PICTURES (ID,NAME,LOCATION,CREATION_DATE,ALBUM_ID) VALUES (1,'albumy','somepath','somedate',(SELECT ID FROM ALBUMS WHERE NAME = 'x'));`

And somehow it always goes into the error "if" (second one) why? what's wrong with my query?

Comment: Have you tried printing out `errMessage`? Might give you a clue...

Comment: Which "error if"?  You have two places where an error can occur.

Comment: I did, it prints 000000

Comment: What's the value of `res`?

Comment: the second one.

Comment: res returns 1. which is false.

Comment: Yes, because you've set it to `nullptr`. You're supposed to pass a pointer to an actual `char*` object as last param to `sqlite3_exec`.

Comment: 1 means SQLITE_ERROR   /* Generic error */
 https://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#SQLITE_ABORT

Comment: @Heehee That last parameter to `sqlite3_exec` is incorrect.  When a function wants a pointer, you're supposed to pass the address of an existing entity.  You don't literally declare a pointer and pass it.

Comment: I used it just like that in my other function and it worked fine, it seems like the problem is with the query itself.

Comment: @Heehee The point is that the error that you're looking for is being hidden due to your improper usage of the last parameter.  `char* errMessage = nullptr;
        res = sqlite3_exec(db, sqlstate, nullptr, nullptr, &errMessage);` -- That's what it should look like.

Comment: The last parameter can be a `nullptr`. In that case no error message is written. But currently you want the error message. https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html

Comment: omg thank you! I had a typo on the creation of the tables and this what was caused it, thank you so much for helping!

Comment: Your code is susceptible to a **SQL injection attack**. Don't write queries like that.